# Read wav file through a socket withought being corrupted PHP and echo it to javascript to play it

Tags: php, sockets, audio, joomla, wav

I am trying to play a WAV file I read it through a TCP Socket
The file is read and everything going well but doesn't play. Through researching I knew there are problem with reading WAV files in PHP.

How can I read it from the socket without being corrupted?

I am using Joomla and the php class echo the data to Javascript to play the WAV file.

This is my PHP:

```
public function myfiles() {

    $store = JRequest::getCmd('st');
    $employee = JRequest::getCmd('emp');
    $myfile = JRequest::getCmd('file');
    $q = 'th/'.$store.'/'.$employee.'/'.$myfile;

    /* Get the port for the WWW service. */
    $service_port = 4040;

    /* Get the IP address for the target host. */
    $address = 127.0.0.1;

    /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($sock === false) {
        return "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
    }

    $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
    } 

    $in = "file ".$q."\n";
    $out = '';

    socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));

    while($buf = socket_read($socket, 2048, MSG_WAITALL)) {
        echo $buf;
    }

    $app = &JFactory::getApplication();
    $app->close();

    socket_close($socket);
}
```

And this is my Javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){$('#link').click(function(){
        $.post("http://127.0.0.1:4040/cognitechTim/index.php?option=com_timhorton&task=myfiles&st=key1&emp=key2&file=value1", function(data, status){
            var myblob = new Blob([data], { type: "audio/wav" });
            var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(myblob);
            var audio = document.getElementById("id2");
            audio.src = objectUrl;
            // Release resource when its loaded
            audio.onload = function(data) {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
            };
            audio.play();
        });
    }); 
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What runs on your server on port 4040? Is that HTTP? If so, you might be reading the headers or something like that.
Have you tryed to dump the content of the generated wave file? Is the size of the file you get the size you expect?

Comment: You Javascript code has an additional "});" you can remove it. You must take a look in @Mathieu's  questions too.

Comment: For the port I am using ngrok. The HTTP Server port is put on 4040 and the TCP server that send me the data through the socket is variable. I was just trying something and put the localhost testing it.

Comment: I have no problem with the connection or receiving the files at all. The file get corrupted. I will try the dumping

Comment: The javascript is working well I removed the additional part thank you. Do you see if there a better way to deal with the data in Javascript may be the drop happens in the playing part ?